# Get the value of dynamically created RadioButtonList

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radiobuttonlist, selectedvalue

I have an asp Radio Button List created this way:

```
ListItem item = new ListItem(string Id, string Name);

RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(item);
```

I can't manage to get the value of the selected item in javascript. The following is my code part:

```
var _rad = document.getElementByName('RadioButtonList1');
for (var j = 0; j < _rad.length; j++) {
        if (_rad[j].checked) {
            _index = _rad[j].value - 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The JavaScript looks fine to me assuming the ASP code is actually setting the `name` attribute to 'RadioButtonList1' and setting the `value` attribute to a number. What do you see when you view the source from your browser?

Answer (score 1):

The method you seek is document.getElement***s***ByName(...), otherwise it should work.

Answer (score 1):

try using jQuery.. that will be a lot easier

check this JS Binn sample.

http://jsbin.com/aviza5/2/edit